# How to set the environment when using `conda build`?

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, conda, conda-build

Trying to take advantage of Conda's build function to install a package not in conda repositories. I've downloaded the source files for the package I want. At the same level I created a folder for my *conda recipes* which contains the `meta.yaml` setting `source: path: ../<package-name>`. So, *look up one directory to find the source files*. This works.

The problem happens at the end when build attempts to test importing the package. It says *x module not found*, but I'm invoking `conda build` from a conda environment where the missing package is installed as shown by `conda list`.

How do I know from what environment `conda build` is performing these tests?

How to set the environment when using `conda build`?

Doesn't help that [Conda Build](https://conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/index.html) docs are full of the word *environment*, but which mostly refers to [environmental variables](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/environment-variables.html) and not [conda environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/environments.html)

```
(base) C:\Users\myhome\PyTools\bin>conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\myhome\Miniconda3_64-4.5.4
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\myhome\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\myhome\.condarc
          conda version : 4.5.4
    conda-build version : 3.18.9
         python version : 3.6.5.final.0
       base environment : C:\Users\myhome\Miniconda3_64-4.5.4  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\myhome\Miniconda3_64-4.5.4\pkgs
                          C:\Users\myhome\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\myhome\Miniconda3_64-4.5.4\envs
                          C:\Users\myhome\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                          C:\Users\myhome\.conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.4 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False

(myenv) C:\Users\myhome\PyTools\bin>conda build <module to install>
...
set PREFIX=C:\Users\myhome\Miniconda3_64-4.5.4\conda-bld\swaggerpy_1568484873987\_test_env
set SRC_DIR=C:\Users\myhome\Miniconda3_64-4.5.4\conda-bld\swaggerpy_1568484873987\test_tmp

(myenv) %SRC_DIR%>call "%SRC_DIR%\conda_test_env_vars.bat"

(myenv) %SRC_DIR%>call "C:\Users\myhome\Miniconda3_64-4.5.4\Scripts\activate.bat" "%PREFIX%"

(%PREFIX%) %SRC_DIR%>IF 0 NEQ 0 exit 1

(%PREFIX%) %SRC_DIR%>IF 0 NEQ 0 exit 1

(%PREFIX%) %SRC_DIR%>"%PREFIX%\python.exe" -s "%SRC_DIR%\run_test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
import: 'swaggerpy'
  File "C:\Users\myhome\Miniconda3_64-4.5.4\conda-bld\swaggerpy_1568484873987\test_tmp\run_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import swaggerpy
  File "C:\Users\myhome\Miniconda3_64-4.5.4\conda-bld\swaggerpy_1568484873987\_test_env\lib\site-packages\swaggerpy\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .swagger_model import load_file, load_json, load_url, Loader
  File "C:\Users\myhome\Miniconda3_64-4.5.4\conda-bld\swaggerpy_1568484873987\_test_env\lib\site-packages\swaggerpy\swagger_model.py", line 15, in <module>
    from swaggerpy.http_client import SynchronousHttpClient
  File "C:\Users\myhome\Miniconda3_64-4.5.4\conda-bld\swaggerpy_1568484873987\_test_env\lib\site-packages\swaggerpy\http_client.py", line 11, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

(%PREFIX%) %SRC_DIR%>IF 1 NEQ 0 exit 1
Tests failed for swaggerpy-0.2.1-py36_0.tar.bz2 - moving package to C:\Users\myhome\Miniconda3_64-4.5.4\conda-bld\broken
WARNING:conda_build.build:Tests failed for swaggerpy-0.2.1-py36_0.tar.bz2 - moving package to C:\Users\myhome\Miniconda3_64-4.5.4\conda-bld\broken
TESTS FAILED: swaggerpy-0.2.1-py36_0.tar.bz2

(myenv) C:\Users\myhome\PyTools\bin>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\myhome\Miniconda3_64-4.5.4\envs\myenv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
...
requests                  2.22.0                   py36_0    anaconda
...
```

Comment: I have a similar problem - how to provide test dependencies for a conda package (on conda-forge, specifically) which are outside of conda (or even conda-forge in my case). I'm tempted to ask a question on SO, but I see your question did not get much attention.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still tackling a similar problem, but I think I can help you at least partially. (Or people having the same problem).

The testing step at the end of your conda-build uses a fresh environment - which will only contain your package and its specific requirements (as specified in `recipe/meta.yaml`. (Note, you're not showing your `meta.yaml`, and therein lies the key to solving this)

If your package requires it, put something like this in your `meta.yaml`:

```
requirements:
  host:
    - python
    - pip
  run:
    - python
    - requests  # here
```

If your package doesn't really require it, but the test code (e.g. unit tests) need it to run, use this kind of section:

```
test:
  requires:
    - nose  # e.g. some test runners
    - requests  # extra deps for test
```

These packages will be installed using `conda`, not `pip`.

How to get something from `pip`, or modify the test environment in an arbitrary way? This one I'm still figuring out...

Comment: Also see here: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#test-requirements